# Draw a shadow for two childs in container, that have no space between them

Tags: android, android-layout

So childs have some strange shadows, that overlapping each other. Is there any way to draw like one shadow for both of them?
The case, I mean is what if they are not even on the same level of view hierarchy.
Here what I want to achieve:
[image: design]

[image: screenshot]
Here`s xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <View
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <View.../>
    <View.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two Child `View` to have the same shadow, just put them in the same `Layout`and add the shadow on the `Layout`

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="8dp">

   <View
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
   <View
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, in that particular case it will work, sorry, i will specify the case, I meant, will edit post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/root"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="200dp"
  android:elevation="8dp"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <View
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:elevation="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"/>
  <View
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:elevation="8dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"/>
  <View.../>
  <View.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thing u can do. you can use Linear layout instead of Relative layout or you can specify position of the view ie,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <View
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view1"/>
    <View.../>
    <View.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```